# How do I see the (default) page size for Microsoft Windows 10?

Tags: c++, windows, windows-10, windows-process

> How do I see the (default) page size for Microsoft Windows 10?

I want to see the default page size of my system (x64), because I want to know how many bytes are fetched on each read operation.

Where do I find this quantity. I've read some places that FileAlignment is set to 512 by default, but I'm not sure whether these things are the same.

Comment: "page size" is usually associated with paging/virtual memory, which has nothing to do with files. What do you actually want to say when you say "page size" ?

Comment: I mean, normally, the CPU fetches a whole page from memory. How do I see the size of the page?

Comment: Actually, the CPU fetches a whole _cache line_ from memory. The OS fetches a whole _page_ from disk.

Comment: A page on x64 is always 4K, that's the hardware page size on x86. That doesn't mean a read operation will read 4K. In the I/O chain, there are many "sizes". You have sectors for HDD, pages (not the same pages) and erase blocks for SSD. There are physical and logical blocks. Then the I/O driver might choose one of these for its transfer size. Or not, or it can be variable. Since a popular samsung SSD have a page size of 8K, and you can only read a whole page, I doubt the driver will only fetch a 4K memory page. So, what do you actually want to know ?

Comment: @ElderBug: I'm fairly certain that x64 supports _large pages_. Also, I don't believe for a second that a Samsung SSD is going to have an 8 kB page size. That would be unbootable (no drivers available to boot, chicken and egg problem)

Comment: @MSalters Of course there are large pages, and huge pages on x64, but that's mostly irrelevant ; pages are still 4K. And most Samsung SSDs do have  8K pages, with 1.5M blocks. That doesn't really matter for booting because these are the hardware sizes, and logical sizes are made compatible. OTH, this probably still matter for performance, so this isn't far-fetched to think the driver would use these sizes for transfer on specific hardwares. Maybe everything use 4K anyway. My point is that it's not clear which size OP wants. I guess it's about transfer size, which MAY be equal to page size.

Answer (score 2):

Call [`GetSystemInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724381(v=vs.85).aspx), look at `dwAllocationGranularity`

Comment: If it's just for the memory page size, you might as well use `dwPageSize`.